# Оптимизация словаря с классами в качестве ключа C#

Tags: c#, .net, словари, сборщик-мусора

Есть класс GeometryExtensions для методов расширения класса Segment. Он хранит в себе словарь, в котором по экземпляру Segment в роли ключа можно обратиться к цвету определенного сегмента. Но проблема в том, что когда программа перестает использовать сегменты, ссылка на них остается в ключе словаря. А так как существует хоть одна действительная ссылка на объект, сборщик мусора не удаляет его. Мне нужно реализовать автоматическое удаление сегментов из словаря, при этом имея доступ только к коду класса GeometryExtensions. Возможно, существуют альтернативные структуры данных, но я не смог найти такую, которая автоматически удаляет объекты с единственной ссылкой.

```
public static class GeometryExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<Segment, Color> segmentColors = new Dictionary<Segment, Color>();

    public static void SetColor(this Segment segment, Color color)
    {
        segmentColors[segment] = color;
    }

    public static Color GetColor(this Segment segment)
    {
        if (segmentColors.ContainsKey(segment))
            return segmentColors[segment];
        return Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужна [`ConditionalWeakTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Кстати `if (segmentColors.ContainsKey(segment)) return segmentColors[segment];` неоптимально, вы делаете 2 запроса к словарю, можно в 2 раза быстрее за 1 запрос `return segmentColors.TrygetValue(segment, out var value) ? value : Color.Black;`. А чтобы ответить на вопрос, непонятно, а что такое `Color`? Структура или класс? А `Segment`? И последний вопрос - сколько максимально по количеству разных элементов может лежать в словаре? Покажите код `Segment` и `Color`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov при условии что `Color` - класс

Comment: @aepot при условии, что Segment - класс. Color может быть чем угодно (но если это не класс, то его придётся самому упаковать)

Comment: @PavelMayorov если это та структура Color, о которой я думаю (RGBA), то ее вес 4 байта :) там нечего упаковывать, ссылка на неё в x64 в 2 раза больше весит, а в x86 столько же.

Comment: @aepot ну, упаковать всё равно придётся из-за ограничений...